# What is the REAL return type of DATEADD() in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

What is the **real** return type of `DATEADD()` in SQL?  Microsoft's documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) says it's a `date`, their documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx) says it's a `datetime`, and Intellisense in Management Studio says it's a `smalldatetime`.

There's quite a bit of difference between those, and I'm surprised Microsoft is contradicting themselves on it this much.  `date` doesn't keep time information, and `smalldatetime` keeps particularly inaccurate time information; in either of those cases, you might as well forget about something like trying to keep track of the number of milliseconds that has passed.

I did try the following experiment:

```
select getdate(), DATEADD(ms, 150, getdate())
```

which reliably yields results such as:

```
2015-01-09 09:54:56.157,    2015-01-09 09:54:56.307
```

This tempts me to believe that neither of the three documented cases are true, but that it actually returns a `datetime2` value instead.  This is in SQL Server 2012, by the way.

So I'm just trying to confirm:

1. Is it really a `datetime2`, or is it a `datetime`?
2. Is this something that's quite consistent between different, relatively modern versions of SQL Server (say, since 2005)?
3. Is there anything else to the story here that I'm not quite seeing, or am I even being thrown off by something?

So essentially this is still one question, which remains, "What is the **real** return type?" but the three points above kind of illustrate where I'm at on this.

**EDIT**

Just to note: On the first link, I was reading primarily off the top of the page, and when I saw that saying `date` and the other link saying `datetime`, I didn't feel like I could take those pages seriously enough to look for anything else that was stated.  Aaron Bertrand clarified though about the differing formatting between *date* and **date** that was used in those documents, though Microsoft probably made a mistake in using italics for very non-technical terms.

Comment: First, in the docs it says `the data type of the date argument` not `the date data type`. Next, never believe the nonsense Intellisense tells you in its tooltips - it's wrong more often than it's right. Now, why do you think `2015-01-09 09:54:56.157` is a `datetime2`? That looks like a `datetime` to me - and it makes sense because the input is `datetime`. Try with `SYSDATETIME()` instead of `GETDATE()`. Also, [please stop using lazy shorthand like `ms`](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations).

Comment: @AaronBertrand In the first link, it says, "Returns a specified date with the specified number interval (signed integer) added to a specified datepart of that date." and in the second link, it says, "Returns a new datetime value by adding an interval to the specified datepart of the specified date."  There might be other statements in those links, but after seeing the main two statements contradict each other like that, it was hard to take anything else in that documentation seriously.

Comment: It's subtle and admittedly confusing, but notice the different formatting throughout the document - when they say *date* they mean "some date/time type" but when they say **date** they mean the explicit data type. This is more obvious when you test what actually happens in SQL Server when you feed different types as input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)

> The return data type is the data type of the date argument, except for string literals.
>   The return data type for a string literal is datetime. An error will be raised if the string literal seconds scale is more than three positions (.nnn) or contains the time zone offset part.

So if the 3rd parameter is one of the `DATE` types, it will return a result of that type, e.g.

```
select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, DATEADD(ms, 150, CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATETIME))
select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, DATEADD(ms, 150, CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATETIME2))
select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, DATEADD(ms, 150, CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS SMALLDATETIME))
```

Returns 3 different types, viz `DateTime, DateTime2 and SmallDateTime` respectively.

Comment: Yep, the common "it depends" answer. +1 though it can also return other types.

Comment: e.g. `SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()));` returns `date`.